# Urn, Expected Value and Covariance

Tags: probability, hypergeometric-function

How would you solve the next problem:
A Urn contains 10 balls; 7 white and 3 black. 2 balls are taken randomly (without replacement), say $X$ white and $Y$ black. $X+Y=2$. Find the Covariance of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Are the two balls picked with or without replacement?

Comment: without, thanks for the remark.

Comment: Its just stated in the problem. Total we are taking 2 balls, $X$ and $Y$ and they add to 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $Y = 2 - X$, we have
\begin{align*}
Cov(X, Y) & = Cov(X, 2 - X) = -Var(X).
\end{align*}
Compute
\begin{align*}
P(X = 0) & = \frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}}
= \frac 1{15}\\
P(X = 1) & = \frac{7\cdot 3}{\binom{10}{2}}
= \frac{7}{15}\\
P(X = 2) & = \frac{\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}}
= \frac{7}{15}\\
E[X] & = \frac{7}{5} \\
E[X^2] & = \frac{7}{3} \\
Var(X) & = \frac 73 - \frac{49}{25} = \frac{175 - 147}{75} = \frac{28}{75} \\
\therefore Cov(X, Y) & = -\frac{28}{75}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Amaazing. Thank you @Tunococ